# check for assignment of two dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

i was wondering how to check a two-dimensional string array for assignment in c#

`string[][] mString; 
bool empty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(mString);`

does not do the trick. some help?

Comment: You want to check is any string is null/empty or all of them are ?

Comment: no, i like to know if this array is assigned or not. any idea, how to proceed?

Comment: mString != null && mString.Length > 0

Comment: it is not that simple...

Comment: @KoolMartin It most certainly is, unless you want to verify that each of the internal arrays are allocated an non-empty.  If that's what you want, then you should ask that.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you want to check?

You do not have a 2-dimensioanl array (that would be `[,]`) but a *jagged array* or *array-of-arrays*.

So you could write:

```
bool empty = mString == null;              // the whole (outer) array

// 1+ sub-arrays is null?
bool empty = (mString == null) || mString.Any(a => a == null)) ;

// any string is null or empty
bool empty = (mString == null) 
      || mString.Any(a => a == null))
      || mString.Any(a => a.Any (s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: ups, i did not know that it is a jagged array. so actually i like to serialize a jagged array and therfore i must check in advance, wether it was initialized.

Comment: Again, what exactly do you mean by `initialized` ?

Comment: hmm, another example might explain what i try to achiee, consider:

  `int mInt;

bool empty = !mInt.Equals(0); 

Console.WriteLine(empty);
`
here i can check if the integer value was assigned. now for the jagged array ;)

Comment: @KoolMartin That actually doesn't work for an int.  Someone may very well have assigned `0` to the `int`.  If you want to know if the jagged array was assigned to the *only* thing you need to do is `array == null)`.